# Flutter returning data from another website

Tags: flutter, dart, saml, url-launcher

I need to integrate Flutter with an already existing SSO for a client. I am using url_launcher to open up an external webpage in Flutter for them to sign on, however I cannot find a way to return data from that website to Flutter via url_launcher. I can't use HTML get/posts because it won't work for the SSO apparently since it uses SAML? Is there a way to circumvent this? I have access to a NodeJS server which I can use for this project, if any solution could be made around that.

Best regards,

Chai

Comment: Why don't have them enter their signup credentials and then call the server API with that data?

Comment: Hi @Andrej, thanks for replying, I don't think the server was developed with any API, I thought it was all based on just networking queries - would it be commonplace for a server to have an API for authentication? I am quite new to all of this.